# join one word lines in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file in the format of one word for line, and I want to join the lines with one space, I tries this, but it does not work

```
for line in file:
    new = ' '.join(line)
    print (new)
```

also this does not work

```
    new = file.replace('\n'', ' ')
    print (new)
```

Comment: strings are appendable so just do new  = line + ' '

Comment: `' '.join(line.rstrip() for line in file)`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [list comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk):

```
whole_string = " ".join([word.strip() for word in file])
print(whole_string)
```

Comment: yes you can, but there is no point in creating a list when you can use a generator. There is a difference.

Comment: @Pynchia, it is actually  more efficient to pass a list,  if you pass a generator python will construct a list anyway as it does two passes over the data

Comment: @PadraicCunningham alright thank you. Do you mean Chad Simmons'/Peter Wood's solution are less optimized than this one? Good to know

Comment: @Pynchia, yes, join checks the size first before it actually joins the strings  so if it did not first create a list when passed a generator  you would not be able to do a second pass over it as the generator would be consumed

Comment: OK, upvoted then! :) @PadraicCunningham why is `join` behaving like that? What's the use of checking the size.. of what?

Comment: @Pynchia, how much space is needed for the output https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/join.h#L54

Comment: @PadraicCunningham are you saying `list(word.strip() for word in words)` is slower than `[word.strip() for word in words]`? I'll have to time it.

Comment: @PeterWood, yes, it is definitely slower.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Well, I never: 2.23 vs 3.12 best of three. About 1.4 times slower.

Answer (score 1):

You can add each line to a list, then join it up after:

```
L = []
for line in file:
    L.append(line.strip('\n'))

print " ".join(L)
```

Your current solution tries to use `join` with a string not a list

Answer (score 1):

A one line solution to this problem would be the following:

`print(open('thefile.txt').read().replace('\n', ' '))`

Answer (score 0):

This is I think what you want..

```
' '.join(l.strip() for l in file)
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another way:

```
with open('yourfilename.txt', 'r') as file:
    words = ' '.join(map(str.rstrip, file))
```

As you can see from several other answers, `file` is an iterator, so you can iterate over it and at each loop it will give you a line read from the file (including the `\n` at the end, that is why we're all stripping it off).

Logically speaking, `map` applies the given function (i.e. `str.rstrip`) to each line read in and the results are passed on to `join`.