# How to convert a string to a list?

Tags: python, string, list

If I have a string:

```
a = 'hello'
```

How do I convert it into a list?

```
a = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A string is an iterable, and a list can be constructed from an iterable. So all you need is

```
a = list(a)
print(a)
```

Output:

> ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']

Comment: Ow oke that works, Thanks!

Comment: Note: a list comprehension `[c for c in a]` should be [faster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108488/are-list-comprehensions-and-functional-functions-faster-than-for-loops)

Comment: @Pynchia I have heard the opposite. If you have any evidence to back up that claim it would be good to see it! (I can't find it in the link you posted.)

Comment: @juanchopanza I just timed it and it's kind of difficult to tell. `python3 -mtimeit -s'l=list(range(1000000))'` and `python3 -mtimeit -s'l=[el for el in range(1000000)]'`. Sometimes one or the other is faster. I must have misunderstood a discussion carried out here a few days ago [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001611/join-one-word-lines-in-a-file)

Comment: @Pynchia Same here, I never managed to spot a significant difference between the two (in python 2, haven't tried python 3.)

Comment: @juanchopanza alright. Thank you for making me check. Good night

Answer (score 0):

Tried to do it differently

**Code:**

```
map(None,"sart")#for python 2.x
#list(map(None,"sart")) for python 3.x
```

**Output:**

```
['s', 'a', 'r', 't']
```

Comment: dowvoter could atleast say y so

Comment: Well, this is little interesting. How does it work?

Comment: @KevinGuan map accepts a iterable and a function `i.e)map(function,iterable)` and a ll the iterable elements are passed to the function and output of map is  list of function out .check this [out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973766/understanding-the-map-function-python)

Comment: And note that this can only work on Python 2. On Python 3 you also need do something like `list(map(None,"sart"))`.

Comment: @KevinGuan you are right :) pleasure is mine

Comment: @KevinGuan just for your curiosity you could also do `map(str,"sart")
`

Comment: Well, it's more interesting now. Maybe I really need see the document about `map()` again :)

Comment: In python 3.5, `list(map(None, 'sart'))` gives `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` which is what I expected.  I'm surprised this works in python 2.

Comment: This is really quite a pointless "solution".

Comment: @juanchopanza I just pointed out it can be done this way also.I did not say it was efficient